# dynamically generated button with different action through array assigning

Tags: android

I want that every textView runtime created show different value in toast but it is only showing the last value in array..

```
        response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        News = response.toString().split("`");

        LinearLayout Newslayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.newslayout);
        while (i < News.length) {

            TextView title = new TextView(this);
            title.setText(News[i]);
            Newslayout.addView(title);
            TextView seeMore = new TextView(this);
            seeMore.setText("See More...");
            seeMore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), News[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
            Newslayout.addView(seeMore);
            TextView title1 = new TextView(this);
            title1.setText("");
            Newslayout.addView(title1);
            i++;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it happens cause the `seeMore` shows the value of `News[i]` and `i` always will equals `News.length - 1`, So you can do something like

```
seeMore.setId(i);
```

and change your code to

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), News[v.getId()], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Good luck**